# How to Stop-Process by command line parameters?

Tags: powershell, command-line, kill

I'm trying to automate some stuff and I need to be able to `Stop-Process` an application started via `dotnet path\to\myProgram.dll`.

I've tried `Stop-Process -Name myProgram -PassThru` but it says it can't find any process like that.
Just doing `Stop-Process -Name dotnet -PassThru` seems a bit spray'n'pray as there are several DotNet programs running and I want to stop a specific one.

How do I find the correct process to give to `Stop-Process`?

Comment: You can stop process only by using process `Name` or by `id` in PowerShell.

Comment: @PrasoonKarunanV So how do I find the Id of the process I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the process running with specific commandline and stop it.

an Example below:

```
$Process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PRocess -Filter "CommandLine='C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe'"
```

or

```
$Process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PRocess -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '%powershell.exe'"
```

then

```
$Process | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

Identify the command line used by the specific dotnet process and filter it with that cmdline.

Comment: Thanks, any chance there's a way to do a wildcard search rather than searching for a very specific command line?

Comment: The filter here uses WQL, so you can do `"CommandLine like '%powershell%'"`

Comment: I ended up using `Stop-Process -Id $Process.ProcessId -PassThru`, couldn't get `Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate` to work properly.